# If/else with button and input

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, input

**EDIT - SOLVED** // As user Win pointed out in the answers, if a function is named click and you try to call it with a HTML button, then it will confuse the function with an inbuilt/standard "click()" function for HTML buttons

Can anybody figure out, why (in the world) this isn't working? I get no bug reports in Chrome, my IDE and/or JSFiddle.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <input id="search" type="text" name="input" placeholder="Search..">
  <button onclick="click()" value="Submit">Get weather</button>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
function click() {
  if (document.getElementById("search").value == "New York") {
    console.log("Loading weather for New York..."); 
  } else {
    console.log("City name isn't valid. Try again");
  }
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nd6f5pp7/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't call the function click, it'll get confused with obj prototypes.

```js
// Grab Input from DOM
var iptSearch = document.getElementById('search')

// Grab Submit button from DOM
var btnGetWeather = document.getElementById('get-weather');

// Add Event Listener
btnGetWeather.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (iptSearch.value === "New York") {
    console.log("Loading weather for New York...");
  } else {
    console.log("City name isn't valid. Try again");
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="search" placeholder="Search..."/>
<button id="get-weather">Get Weather</button>
```

Or, if you want to follow the example code you've given. Use the below:

```js
function getWeather() {
  if (document.getElementById('search').value === "New York") {
    console.log("Loading weather for New York...");
  } else {
    console.log("City name isn't valid. Try again");
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="search" type="text" name="input" placeholder="Search..">
  <button onclick="getWeather()">Get weather</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't know that wasn't allowed. Will accept your answer in 10 minutes, when SO lets me do so.

Comment: better use listener instead of `onclick`

Comment: @Win Awesome, thanks for also showing how it could be done with eventlistener. I appreciate all the help a lot! :)

Comment: @thesystem no problem :) glad to be of help

Comment: Thank you for the solution 5 yeas later and I just needed that :D !